# How to get product attributes (weight, dimension.height..) in php

Tags: commerce, theming

I am fairly new to drupal commerce and php so pardon the dumb newbie question. I downloaded commerce_order_ftp_export and after updating it to the devel version I was able to get it working. It ftps an xml file whenever an order is completed.

Now I needed to customize the xml so I can import it into stamps.com. I was successful at changing the shipping information, but I am having trouble getting the product weight and dimensions (width, height & length). I am updating 
modules/commerce_order_ftp_export/commerce-order-ftp-export.tpl.php
and code that works looks like:

```
<?php $shipping_id = $order->commerce_customer_shipping['und'][0]['profile_id'];
$shipping_address = $profiles[$shipping_id]->commerce_customer_address['und'][0];
?>

  <Recipient>
    <AddressFields>
      <FullName><?php print $shipping_address['name_line']; ?></FullName>
```

But I don't know how to access the products, I tried `dpm($products[$product['product_id']]->getPropertyInfo())` in the following code to try to get more information about the product, but it is giving me an error. How show debugging info so I can see the properties of the product or how can I write a debug test page that shows that info?

```
<?php foreach ($order->commerce_line_items['und'] as $key=>$line_item) { ?>
  <?php if ($line_items[$line_item['line_item_id']]->type == 'product'): ?>
  <OrderItemDetail>
    <LineNumber><?php print $key+1; ?></LineNumber>
    <?php foreach ($line_items[$line_item['line_item_id']]->commerce_product['und'] as $product) { ?>
    <ProductSKU><?php print $products[$product['product_id']]->sku; ?></ProductSKU>
    <ProductWeight><?php print dpm($products[$product['product_id']]->getPropertyInfo()); ?></ProductWeight>
        <?php } ?>
    <Quantity><?php print $line_items[$line_item['line_item_id']]->quantity; ?></Quantity>
    <Price><?php print $products[$product['product_id']]->commerce_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['amount']; ?></Price>
  </OrderItemDetail>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php } ?>
```